# I can't get the items from the FirebaseRealtimeDB to recyclerview

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I want to display image from Firebase Realtime DB. But I think it can not run loadPhoto() in MainUpload.java

In Realtime DB
[image]

```
Oncreate(){
    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_main_list);
        int numberOfColumns = 3;
        GridLayoutManager mGridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplication(),numberOfColumns);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mGridLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mItem = new ArrayList<>();
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(mItem);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
        
        //clearAll();
        loadPhoto();
        
        
        DividerItemDecoration dividerItemDecoration=new DividerItemDecoration(mRecyclerView.getContext(),mGridLayoutManager.getOrientation());
        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(dividerItemDecoration);
        
        mRecyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), mRecyclerView, new ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
        
                ItemObject itemObject = mItem.get(position);
        
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title",itemObject.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("photo",itemObject.getPhoto());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
}
```

loadPhoto() function

```
private void loadPhoto() {
        FirebaseUser currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        String key = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getInstance().getReference("users")
                .child(currentUser.getUid()).child("Object").getKey();
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users")
                .child(currentUser.getUid()).child("Object").child(key);
        if(databaseReference !=null) {
            databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        ItemObject itemObject = new ItemObject();
                        //여기서 에러
                        AESCoderAndriod aesCoderAndriod = new AESCoderAndriod();
                        try {
                            String En1 = snapshot.child("photo").getValue().toString();
                            byte[] En2 = En1.getBytes();
                            byte[] Dn1 = aesCoderAndriod.decrypt(seed, En2);
                            Bitmap Dn2 = byteArrayToBitmap(Dn1);
                            Uri Dn3 = getImageUri(getApplication(), Dn2);
                            itemObject.setPhoto(Dn3.toString());
                            itemObject.setTitle(snapshot.child("title").getValue().toString());
                            mItem.add(itemObject);
                            Log.e("test", Dn3.toString());
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                        //   itemObject.setPhoto(snapshot.child("Photo").getValue().toString());
                    }
                    //myAdapter= new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(),mItem);
                    // mRecyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);

                    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                }
            });
        }


    }
```

ItemObject.java

```
public class ItemObject {

        private String title;
        private String Photo;

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getPhoto() {
            return Photo;
        }

        public void setPhoto(String photo){

            this.Photo=photo;
        }

        public ItemObject(String title, String photo) {
        this.title = title;
        this.Photo=photo;
        }
        public ItemObject() {}

    }
```

Comment: First of all, stop ignoring errors. Use `Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage());`. Do you get something printed out in the logcat?

Comment: "I think it can not run loadPhoto() in MainUpload.java" Why not? When you run this code in a debugger and step through it line by line, which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0):

**GET DATA TO CUSTOM OBJECTS**

First thing I want you to know. When retrieving data from Firebase and placing them inside the custom object, in your case ItemModel, you can do this easily like this:

```
ItemModel model = snapshot.getValue(ItemModel.class)
```

This is IF snapshot is only one child. If you have more childs in a snapshot you can still do it like this:

```
List<ItemModel> models = new ArrayList<>();
for (DataSnapshot tempModel : snapshot.getChildren()) {
     models.add(tempModel.getValue(ItemModel.class));
}
```

But be sure that ItemModel and your fields in Firebase RDB are the same. Also you need a public empty constructor in your ItemModel.class. Just write this:

```
public ItemModel() { //default constructor}
```

---

**USE BREAKPOINTS TO ANALYZE YOUR CODE**

This is probably not the answer to your question but it's something for everyone coming with a problem to be solved here. First of all, if something is not working never give up on it first and come here for help. There are multiple solutions to check WHAT IS NOT WORKING!! This is the process for that.

In your case, you are not sure if `loadPhoto()` is working or even if it gets called from MainUpload.class. To check this, in your debug process you can use:

- Breakpoints: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug
- Log: Use Log to write something to realize where the compiler was before it got crash or anything else.

If you are using Log just write something like Log.d("LOAD PHOTO"). Write this in the beginning of the `loadPhoto()` function and you'll know it entered that function. Logic is simple, just use it. Even better is to use breakpoints where you can go line by line to see what is going on with your code (F8 - advance single line, F9 - advance to next breakpoint, release if there is none).